# App promo codes - do they renew?

Tags: ios, applications

A client of mine has generated all 100 promo codes for their app without considering that they are valid for only 28 days.

Do they ever regenerate? If I made version 2.0 of the App would that enable new promo codes?

It's just naivety on the part of the client.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 1):

They will regenerate and make the old codes invalid.

"They become invalid if a new version of the app becomes available" ... "You can request up to 100 promo codes for every version of each platform of your app"  - [Apple Developer - Providing Promo Codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html)